# IE11 Object doesn't support property or method 'normalize'

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, diacritics, normalize

I'm using string.normalize to remove diacritics from a string. This javascript works fine in other browsers, but in IE11 it is throwing an error that says "Object  doesn't support property or method 'normalize'

```
function removeDiacritics(text) {
    return text.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
}
```

Comment: Right, it's not supported.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize  What is your question?

Comment: How to remove diacritics in IE? Or make it not throw an error?

Answer (score 6):

[`normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) was only added in ES2015. IE11 doesn't support virtually any of ES2015, including `normalize`. You'll need a polyfill, or to not use `normalize`. (The [`core.js` project](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) doesn't have a polyfill for it, but mentions a module called [`unorm`](https://github.com/walling/unorm/) that does normalization...)

Comment: I've never used a polyfill before so I'd appreciate some help. I ran 'npm install unorm' in the root folder of my project and it ran successfully, I see unorm added to package.json, but the javascript line is still throwing the error in IE. Is there another step I've missed?

Comment: `@Erica, After install the unorm, please check the solution Explorer, make sure the project includes the unorm package, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEGRU.png). Then, you could add the unorm reference to your web page, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaRzm.png). Since, not sure whether your application is an angular application or web application, I just test it on web application.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the [unorm](https://github.com/walling/unorm) polyfill will provide support for normalize.